# POST API: System.HttpResponse[Status: Forbidden , StatusCode=403 ]

Tags: apex, callout, post

I am working callout to post my JSON. When I test my JSON at PostMan it's all correct but when same JSON with my api, I got ' System.HttpResponse[Status: Forbidden , StatusCode=403 ]' ( 403 Confirmed... ). I'am stuk in this for a long time. Any efrot will be highly appreciated. 
Here is my POST process.

```
  public with sharing class LeadPost {

@future (callout=true)
public static void callout( string json_leadID){

    // Test Email address
    string email = 'umer121@gmail.com';

    string parsedID;
    string leadName;
    String leadEmail;
    String leadPhone;

 // Address Array 'addressList' 
    string addressApartment, addressArea, addressBlock, addressBuildingName, addressCity, addressCountry, addressLat, addressLng, addressPostCode, addressState, addressStreet, addressText;

// Vendor Bank Details object fields 'vendorBankDetails'
    string accountName, accountNumber, bic, iban, sortCode, vat;

// Vendor busness info object 'vendorBusiness'
    string cod, companyName, contractEnd, contractOngoing, contractStart, deliveryCharges, industry, invoiceEmail, noOfEmp, paymentTerminal, trialDays;

// Vendor fares info object 'vendorFares'
    string baseFare, dropOff, perKMCharges, pickUp, radius;

// Vendor personal info Object 'vendorPersonal'
    string enabled, firstName, language, lastName, middleName, password, phoneNumber, username;

// END var JSON strings

    // creat JSON
    // creat JSON

        system.debug('LeadPOST JSON: '+json_leadID); // pass // String jsonString

        string leadID = json_leadID;
        system.debug('lad: '+leadID);
        String jsonID = JSON.serialize(leadID);

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(json_leadID);
        while(parser.nextToken()!= null) {
        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            parser.nextValue();
            if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'Id') {
                parsedID = parser.getText();
            }
            else if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'Name'){
                leadName = parser.getText();
            }
            else if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'Phone'){
                leadPhone = parser.getText();
            }
            else if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'email'){
                leadEmail = parser.getText();
            }
        }
        }

        //system.debug('This is LEAD ID test: ' +parsedID +' , Lead Name: '+leadName+ ' , Lead Phone Number: ' +leadPhone+' , Lead Email: '+leadEmail);

        string jsonPost='{ "addressList": [ { "addressApartment": "'+addressApartment+'", "addressArea": "'+addressArea+'", "addressBlock": "'+addressBlock+'", "addressBuildingName": "'+addressBuildingName+'", "addressCity": "'+addressCity+'", "addressCountry": "'+addressCountry+'", "addressLat": "'+addressLat+'", "addressLng": "'+addressLng+'", "addressPostCode": "'+addressPostCode+'", "addressState": "'+addressState+'", "addressStreet": "'+addressStreet+'", "addressText": "'+addressText+'" },\n'+
                                        '{ "addressApartment": "'+addressApartment+'", "addressArea": "'+addressArea+'", "addressBlock": "'+addressBlock+'", "addressBuildingName": "'+addressBuildingName+'", "addressCity": "'+addressCity+'", "addressCountry": "'+addressCountry+'", "addressLat": "'+addressLat+'", "addressLng": "'+addressLng+'", "addressPostCode": "'+addressPostCode+'", "addressState": "'+addressState+'", "addressStreet": "'+addressStreet+'", "addressText": "'+addressText+'" } ],\n'+
                                        ' "vendorBankDetails": { "accountName": "'+accountName+'", "accountNumber": "'+accountNumber+'", "bic": "'+bic+'", "iban": "'+iban+'", "sortCode": "'+sortCode+'", "vat": "'+vat+'" },\n'+
                                        ' "vendorBusiness": { "cod": "'+cod+'", "companyName": "'+companyName+'", "contractEnd": "'+contractEnd+'", "contractOngoing": "'+contractOngoing+'", "contractStart": "'+contractStart+'", "deliveryCharges": "'+deliveryCharges+'", "industry": "'+industry+'", "invoiceEmail": "'+invoiceEmail+'", "noOfEmp": "'+noOfEmp+'", "paymentTerminal": "'+paymentTerminal+'", "trialDays": "'+trialDays+'" },\n'+
                                        ' "vendorFares": { "baseFare": "6", "dropOff": "3", "pickUp": "3", "radius": "2", "perKMCharges":"2" },\n'+
                                        ' "vendorPersonal": { "enabled": "1", "firstName": "firstName", "language": "language", "lastName": "lastName", "middleName": "middleName", "phoneNumber": "phoneNumber", "username": "'+email+'" } }';

    // Callout

    // /*
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('http://test-url....');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');


        request.setBody(jsonPost);
        system.debug(' POST JSON: '+ jsonPost);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('Helper class--Lead Resposne: ' + response);

        if(response.getStatusCode() == 403){
            system.debug('403 Confirmed...');
        }
        else if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        }
        else {
            System.debug('response.getBody() :  '+response.getBody());
        }

    // */
    // END Eallout
    }
```

}

Comment: Does your user in the SF account have the 'API Enabled' permission? I mean the one whose sessionId you use for Authorization header? https://www.matchmyemail.com/wiki/errors-and-alerts/http-error-getting-salesforce-features-403-forbidden/

Comment: Yes, I did cross checking and it's enabled. I am doing this in trailhead playground org. Is that allowed in trailhead org ?

Comment: A Trailhead Playground is actually a Developer Edition (DE) that has been customized with Trailhead-specific bells and whistles.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I1TXQA0

Comment: So, whats the issue if DE is allowing this ?

Comment: Can you please add here th endpoint you use in POST method, so I can check it? Erase the org domain from it if you want, I just need everything that goes after .com/

Comment: http://_____/vendor-management-service/Lahore/courioo/1.0/vendor/register-vendor

Comment: You seem to be calling a non-Salesforce web service. It's unlikely we can help you without more detail on what the requirements of the service are relative to the Apex code you have written. I don't see any indication that you are authenticating, for example.

Comment: Yes, It's non salesforce web service. I want to expose my json data to an external service.

Comment: There is no authentication header, Can you check if you are using some type of authentication form in postman. Normally post method needs some sort of authentication

Comment: A big thanks for your efforts. But it's resolved now. Issue was about ' I was trying to access service on local server which was restricted. Now I deployed me services to aws and it's working fine.'